# Filling out a PDF / form using Winform application

Tags: c#, winforms, pdf

I have a 2-page PDF that I want to overlay information on (think of a form that someone manually fills out) using a C#/.NET Windows application. After this form is generated, it will need to be previewed and printed (exported into a graphic or PDF is nice, but not a requirement).

At first glance, I'm thinking of two ways to do this:

1. Use a PDF manipulator like iTextSharp, take a copy of the blank PDF form, and add text to the PDF. Then, launch Adobe Reader to do a print or preview.
2. Convert the PDF into a graphic, and put the graphic into a C# Report. Then, overlay text fields onto the report, and use a .NET ReportViewer control to preview and print the report.

The text does not need to be searchable or copyable or have any of the cool things that PDF gives me, so I'm leaning towards the second option. Am I missing anything, or is there something I'm not thinking of? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use #1 extensively and it works perfectly. You shouldn't have any problems, it's rather easy (just need to make the fields writeable and use a FDF file and merge it with the PDF file). At least that's how we did it.

Comment: Now, this form doesn't have any editable fields -- it's pretty much all text and graphics. So, it's a matter of adding form fields to the PDF, then generating a FDF file, then merging the two?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Sorry for the slow response.