# Auto populate PDF document

Tags: c#, winforms, report-viewer2010, report-viewer2012

Here's my requirement:
I am using C# Winforms, Reportviewer 11.0.
I have a Checklist document thats available both in PDF and Word formats. It has some header information such as the Contact , geographic location that needs to be programatically filled out and the body has a Yes/No checklist to indicate which reports were run. Original document has placeholders to fill out this information.

There's a Reports tab in my Winform app that has a list of reports. This checklist should be placed somewhere in the Reports section of the app. I am wondering what would be the best way to include this checklist document with information programatically filled in.

I hope this description is understandable.

Thanks much

Answer (score 0):

This thread got me started 
[Filling out a PDF / form using Winform application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2299620/filling-out-a-pdf-form-using-winform-application?rq=1)
I decided to go with iTextSharp. CodeProject has an implementation on this:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23112/Fill-in-PDF-Form-Fields-using-the-Open-Source-iTex

I was not getting any field count from AcroFields initially. So in order to fix that, i converted the non editable PDF to editable using Acrobat Pro. Now I am able to write to the PDF file.